# Return one row in a view based on a left join column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have a view where I am  replacing the foreign key values with their reference values through a series of left joins.

One of these tables, can have a many to one relationship where I'm joining

```
Example.exampleid = SLA.exampleId.
```

My issue is that the SLA table has a column where the `SLa.type` can be `A` or `B` and then the `SLA.value` will have a number. This creates a duplicate row in my view where the only difference is the `SLA.type` and `SLA.value`.

I want it to return these columns where the `SLA.type` is `A` and still not break the view when there is nothing to find in the table for a given `example.exampleId`

E.g. My view select query in a concise shortform:

```
Select Example.exampleId, SLA.type, SLA.value
FROM Example 
   LEFT JOIN SLA ON Example.exampleId = SLA.exampleId
WHERE SLA.type <> "B" OR SLA.type IS NULL or SLA.value IS NULL
```

An example.exampleId will only ever have two rows in the SLA table, one for type A and one for type B.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `SLA.type <> "B"` condition into the join clause because it will apply to the right hand side column only in this case. In the weher clause the condition applies to the whole dataset:

```
Select Example.exampleId, SLA.type, SLA.value
FROM Example 
   LEFT JOIN SLA ON Example.exampleId = SLA.exampleId and SLA.type <> "B"
```

Although, I would consider using `SLA.type = "A"`, just in case you will introduce a new SLA type.